# Android getAssets().list python file tree script

Tags: android, python, json

getAssets().list in my android app is too slow. I have almost 3000 of files and on some devices it takes MINUTES to just get all filenames. 
So, instead, I want to create a json file with python script with file tree inside and it must be easy to find all files and dirs (names) from particular subdirectory.

So default implementation without json is something like this:

```
public String[] listAssets(String path) throws IOException {        
    return getAssets().list(path);
}
```

Now I have to use loaded json filetree to find contents of particular path

Here's a python script:

```
import os
import json
path = "/Users/xxx/somepath"

def path_to_dict(path):
    d = {'name': os.path.basename(path)}
    if os.path.isdir(path):
        d['type'] = "directory"
        d['children'] = [path_to_dict(os.path.join(path,x)) for x in os.listdir\
(path)]
    else:
        d['type'] = "file"
    return d

with open("tree.json", "w") as tf:
    tf.write(json.dumps(path_to_dict(path)))
```

Script is taken from stackoverflow. Now, I have an issue how to parse it:

```
public String[] listAssets(String path) throws IOException {        
    //return getAssets().list(path);
    try {
        JSONArray assets = fileTree.getJSONArray("children");
        if (path.equals("")) { //asking for root dir
            String[] names = new String[assets.length()];
            for(int i = 0; i < assets.length(); i++){
                names[i] = assets.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            }
            return names;
        }
        else { //same subdirectory
            String[] parts = path.split(Pattern.quote("/"));
            JSONArray array = findSubdirectory(parts, 0, assets);
            String[] names = new String[array.length()];
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++){
                names[i] = array.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
            }
            return names;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

I'm splitting path by "/" and have to somehow get through all subdirectories and recursively find the right one, but I don't know how to implement this "findSubdirectory" method.

Comment: If you are going to generate a file, why not generate a Java class, and save yourself the parsing work? [Here is a book sample](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Gradle/Staticizer) that generates a Java class from a JSON file, to avoid the embedding and parsing that you're dealing with.

Comment: `I have almost 3000 of files and on some devices it takes MINUTES`. Hard to believe. For a test i put 1019 files in assets folder. My assets explorer lists them in the blink of an eye. Show your code.

Comment: Depends on device. On Nexus 6P it takes half of seconds. On old lenovo tablet it takes 150 seconds from my tests. I have a lot of subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out different (most efficient way):

declarations:

```
HashMap<String, String> files;
JSONObject fileTree;
```

in onCreate():

```
try {
    fileTree = new JSONObject(readTextFromAssets("tree.json", "\n"));
}
catch (Exception e){
    e.printStackTrace();
}

files = toMap(fileTree);
```

main function:

```
public String[] listAssets(String path) throws IOException {
    String f = files.get(path);
    if(f != null){
        return f.split(Pattern.quote("|"));
    }
    String[] l = getAssets().list(path);
    files.put(path, join(l, "|"));
    return l;
}
```

helper functions:

```
public static String join(String[] values, String delimiter) {
    StringBuilder strbuf = new StringBuilder();

    boolean first = true;

    for (String value : values)
    {
        if (!first) { strbuf.append(delimiter); } else { first = false; }
        strbuf.append(value);
    }

    return strbuf.toString();
}

public static HashMap<String, String> toMap(JSONObject object) {
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    try {
        Iterator<String> keysItr = object.keys();
        while (keysItr.hasNext()) {
            String key = keysItr.next();
            String value = object.getString(key);
            map.put(key, value);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return map;
}
```

Saving cache:

```
    fileTree = new JSONObject(files);
    File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES), "files.jpg");
    try {
        BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file));
        output.write(fileTree.toString());
        output.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```